# Automatically attach SQL Server database during/after installation

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Please tell me how can we attach SQL Server database (SQL Server 2005) during installation or after installation using c#.net (desktop application). We can create a form to get details of connection string (user id, pass, server name etc..) . please tell me how can we automatically attach database with SQL Server using .net

Comment: please don't put tags like " (c#.net)" in the title. Please leave them in the tags.

Comment: You cannot "attach" a SQL Server database (except for the SQL Server Express version). You **create** a database and then your software **connects to** that database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execute a full create database script with your tables, SPs etc. the same way you do any insert i.e. call `ExecuteNonQuery` method.

Is it what you were asking or you need something more?

Comment: its a good idea.. but i was asking about attaching database programmatically

Comment: Do you mean that you already have .mdf file  and you want to attach it?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the SQL Express Edition it attach automatically database.

Answer (score 1):

You should add a Service-Based Database to your project as shown: 
[image]
This way you will an app.config setting for automatic Db Attach as well : [image]

 All that you will need to do after that is change the database server instance name.